# Get total utilised time on every hour using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Input:

```
-------------------------------------------
start_time           |  end_time           
-------------------------------------------
2019-03-28 04:00:00  |  2019-03-28 04:15:00
2019-03-28 04:00:00  |  2019-03-28 04:30:00
2019-03-28 04:40:00  |  2019-03-28 04:50:00
2019-03-28 04:50:00  |  2019-03-28 05:15:00
2019-03-28 05:15:00  |  2019-03-28 05:45:00
2019-03-28 06:15:00  |  2019-03-28 06:45:00
2019-03-28 07:00:00  |  2019-03-28 08:00:00
2019-03-29 04:00:00  |  2019-03-29 04:15:00
2019-03-29 04:00:00  |  2019-03-29 04:30:00
2019-03-29 04:40:00  |  2019-03-29 04:50:00
2019-03-29 04:50:00  |  2019-03-29 05:15:00
2019-03-29 05:15:00  |  2019-03-29 05:45:00
2019-03-29 06:15:00  |  2019-03-29 06:45:00
2019-03-29 07:00:00  |  2019-03-29 08:00:00
```

I want to get total utilised time for an every hour on across dates. Duration can overlap between on same duration as well.

expecting output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
duration                                 |  utilised_time
------------------------------------------------------------
2019-03-28 12:00 - 2019-03-28 01:00      |    0
2019-03-28 01:00 - 2019-03-28 02:00      |    0
2019-03-28 02:00 - 2019-03-28 03:00      |    0
2019-03-28 03:00 - 2019-03-28 04:00      |    0
2019-03-28 04:00 - 2019-03-28 05:00      |    50
2019-03-28 05:00 - 2019-03-28 06:00      |    45
2019-03-28 06:00 - 2019-03-28 07:00      |    45
2019-03-28 07:00 - 2019-03-28 08:00      |    60
2019-03-28 08:00 - 2019-03-28 09:00      |    0
2019-03-29 12:00 - 2019-03-29 01:00      |    0
2019-03-29 01:00 - 2019-03-29 02:00      |    0
2019-03-29 02:00 - 2019-03-29 03:00      |    0
2019-03-29 03:00 - 2019-03-29 04:00      |    0
2019-03-29 04:00 - 2019-03-29 05:00      |    50
2019-03-29 05:00 - 2019-03-29 06:00      |    45
2019-03-29 06:00 - 2019-03-29 07:00      |    45
2019-03-29 07:00 - 2019-03-29 08:00      |    60
2019-03-29 08:00 - 2019-03-29 09:00      |    0
```

How we can achieve this using PSQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the hours using `generate_series()`.  Then use a `left join` and `aggregation`:

```
select g.ts, g.ts + interval '1 hour',
       sum(extract(epoch from (least(g.ts + interval '1 hour', i.end_time) -
                               greatest(g.ts, i.start_time)
                              )
                   )
          ) / 60 as duration_in_minutes
from generate_series('2019-03-28 12:00:00'::timestamp, '2019-03-29 08:00 - 2019-03-29 09:00:00'::timestamp, interval '1 hour'
                    ) g(ts) left join
       input i
       on i.start_time < g.ts + interval '1 hour' and
          i.end_time > g.ts
group by g.ts
order by g.ts;
```

Your results and your question are unclear about what hours you want.  You explicitly state "I want to get total utilised time for an every hour on across dates."  However, your sample results do not have every hour.  You can filter the hours you want using a `where` clause.